# $H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}) = H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$ for $d = 2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In remark 17 of the book [1], it is stated that

$$H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}) = H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})
\tag{1}
$$

for all spatial dimensions $d \geq 2$. Here $H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$ is defined to be the closure of
$C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$.

I think I am able to prove this for $d \geq 3$.
In my proof I make use of the fact that, for $d \geq 3$,

$$\frac{n^2}{n^d} \rightarrow 0 \qquad \textrm{as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

Clearly this argument doesn't work with $d=2$.
Does anybody know how
$H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}) = H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$
can be proven in the $d=2$ case?

---

Here is my attempted proof.

Introduce a cut-off function $\eta \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$
such that $0 \leq \eta \leq 1$ and

$$
\eta(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{ if } |x| \leq 1, \\
0 & \textrm{ if } |x| \geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$

Let $\eta_n(x) = \eta(nx)$. Then, to prove $(1)$, it suffices to show that for any $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$ we have
$$ \| \eta_n u \|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} \rightarrow 0.$$
However, note that $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}) 
\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$
is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$
(see e.g. Item 3 of Remark 1.27 in [https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf](https://math.aalto.fi/%7Ejkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf)).
Therefore, we can assume without loss of generality that $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\}) 
\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$.
Now, using dominated convergence, it is easily checked that
$$
\| \eta_n u \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} \rightarrow 0, \\
\| \eta_n (\nabla u) \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} \rightarrow 0.
$$
Therefore, since $\nabla (\eta_n u) = (\nabla \eta_n) u + \eta_n (\nabla u)$, it remains to show that
$$
\| (\nabla \eta_n) u \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} \rightarrow 0.
$$

However, because $u \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})$ we have
$$
\| (\nabla \eta_n) u \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} 
\leq 
\| \nabla \eta_n \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} 
\| u \|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} 
$$

and therefore it suffices to show that

$$
\| \nabla \eta_n \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} 
\rightarrow 0.
$$

Let $B_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \| x\|\ \leq 2/n \}$. We see that

$$
\| \nabla \eta_n \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})}^2
= \int_{B_n} \| \nabla \eta_n \|^2
\leq n^2  \| \nabla \eta \|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})}
\int_{B_n} 1
\leq C \frac{n^2}{n^d}.
$$

Thus if $d \geq 3$ we get
$\| \nabla \eta_n \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\})} 
\rightarrow 0$ as desired, completing the proof.

---

[1]: *Brezis, Haim*, [**Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7), Universitext. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-70913-0/pbk; 978-0-387-70914-7/ebook). xiii, 599 p. (2011). [ZBL1220.46002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1220.46002).

Comment: Could you show your proof?

Comment: Have you tried mimicking the proof the case of $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)=H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$? If I remember correctly, it uses the fact that integrable functions have most of their integral mass on a compact set. You then proceed to construct cutoff function, which approximate your sobolev function and the cutoff functions get approximatex by $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ functions. Use an $\epsilon /3$ argument to conclude. It should work exactly the same here, but then again, I haven't really "done the math" in this case.

Comment: I would try something like the following. Take $u\in H^1(\mathbb R^2\setminus 0)$ and let’s take a double approximation of $u$. First, you approximate $u$ by $u_n(x):=(\eta(x/n)-\eta(nx))u(x)$, where $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ and equal to 1 close to the origin (you have to show this is bounded and convergent in $H^1$). Then you regularize $u_n$ with $u_n^\varepsilon$ and show that these functions are test functions (this should be trivial) and show that the regularized sequence converges in $H^1$..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $H^1(\Omega) = H^1_0(\Omega)$ for $\Bbb{R}^N\setminus \{0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168626/prove-h1-omega-h1-0-omega-for-bbbrn-setminus-0)

Comment: @rebo79 It seems that answer only works for $N>2$, for $N=2$ I'm not sure (nor, it seems, is the person who wrote that answer).

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I've added my proof. Thanks for the suggestion. It seems like your suggestion is basically what I am doing in my proof. The problem is that, when we multiply $u$ by the cut-off function, it's not clear whether that converges to 0 when $N=2$.

Comment: @F.Conrad I have seen the proof of that, but in that case it involves cut-off functions whose support is increasing, so as to "approximate" all of $\mathbb{R}^d$. In this case we want to use cut-off functions whose support is shrinking, so as to "approximate" the single point at the origin.

Comment: (A suggestion- make the title only about the remaining $N=2$ case so that it is not closed as a dupe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to be an exercise in a different book (Exercise 2.2, S.T. Kuroda’s *An Introduction to Scattering Theory*) with the hint that in the case $d=2$, we need to find a replacement for $n x$. Let $\eta$ be radial such that
$$ \eta(|x|)=\begin{cases} 1 & |x|<1/4 \\ 0 & |x|\ge 1/2\\ \text{smooth }&\text{in between}\end{cases}$$
(So far basically the same as yours)
and define for $\sigma>0$,
$$ \eta_\sigma(x) :=\eta(|x|^\sigma) \in C^\infty_c(B_{2^{-1/\sigma}}(0))$$
(That’s the weird part.) with the intention to send $\sigma\to 0$. Note that $\eta_\sigma \to 0$ at every $x\neq 0$. Now we continue like your proof with dominated convergence for $d>2$ and end up needing to estimate $\|\nabla\eta_\sigma\|_{L^2}$, and this goes like so:
\begin{align}
\|\nabla\eta_\sigma\|_{L^2}^2 &= \int_{|x|\le 2^{-1/\sigma}}|(\nabla \eta)(|x|^\sigma)|^2 \sigma^2 |x|^{2\sigma-2}dx \\ &\lesssim_{\|\nabla \eta\|_{L^\infty}}\sigma^2 \int_0^{2^{-1/\sigma}} r^{2\sigma-2}rdr\\&\lesssim \frac{\sigma^2}{2\sigma} r^{2\sigma}\Big|_{r=0}^{2^{-1/\sigma}} \\& \lesssim \sigma \to 0,
\end{align}whence the result.

---

*Kuroda, S. T.*, An introduction to scattering theory, Lecture Notes Series, No. 51. Aarhus: Aarhus Universitet, Matematisk Institut. Not consecutively paged. (1978). [ZBL0407.47003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0407.47003).

Comment: @Aguy thank you for the edit and sorry for the carelessness!